# How to save information from JTable to a File?

Tags: java, swing, io, jtable, jframe

Here is my case:

So far my group and I, managed to read information from an external file and place it in a JTable. But we need an update button. So we guess we should take all the information from JTable after editting something inside it, and replace it with the current information in the same file. So we kind of think we have to overwrite the old file.

So far we got this: (for int i... is a part of the code but can't get it inside the grey area :P)

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    p += model.getValueAt(i, 0) + " "
                + model.getValueAt(i, 1) + " "
                + (Integer) model.getValueAt(i, 2) + " "
                + model.getValueAt(i, 3) + " "
                + (Integer)model.getValueAt(i, 4) + " "
                + model.getValueAt(i, 5) + " "
                + model.getValueAt(i, 6) + " "
                + model.getValueAt(i, 7) + " "
                + (Integer)model.getValueAt(i, 8) + "\n";
}

// Update File
SaveMember sm = new SaveMember();
sm.update(p);
```

Inside our SaveMember.java we got:

```
public void update(String x) throws Exception {
    File f = new File("Members/Members.txt");
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(f);  
    output.print(x);
```

So by now when we go and change the data and press the button update, it doesn't do anything at all, and doesn't replace the old data with the new.. Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: To use code formatting, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting editing form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. If you have double checked that your code is executed at all (maybe you forgot to attach the ActionListener to your button - we all do that from time to time...) try flush the output stream and close the stream afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your code in the for loop is executed at all. Set a breakpoint after the for loop and inspect the string *p*. If you are not familiar with debugging, print the string to the console with `System.out.println(p)`.

If your code is NOT executed: Check why the method your code is in is not called. Perhaps you forgot to attach an action listener to your update button or the action listener has an early return under some circumstances.

If your code is executed: What do you do with the exception that is thrown by the method *update*? Make sure to log it with your logger or print it to the console (again via `System.out.println(exc)`). If you get a *FileNotFoundException* the path to the file is not correct.